# Date.Time on Windows Azure returns Tommorrows date

Tags: datetime

I have code that uses the call DateTime.Today. When I debug/run the APP on the local machine it returns the correct date, for e.g. 11/21/2017. However, when the application runs on the Azure Server, it returns 1 day ahead, for e.g. 11/22/2017 . The location for the resource group is West US. I can of course adjust for the discrepancy, but want to know if there is a way to set the timezone on the service in addition the location.

thanks

Comment: I suspect it's returning UTC as it's now 2017/11/22T02:42:00.000Z.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, John. I am currently deploying to Azure right now, and will revert back. thank you for responding so quickly John